# OnLoadFinished suddenly not called anymore after update

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a list of items, each item has an editable quantity. When I edit the quantity, the database is updated and I receive a new cursor in the fragment. This all works well, except when you update the quantity a number of times, the onLoadFinished method is not called anymore. This can happen after 5 updates or after 200 updates: I can't reproduce the bug on command. The update is executed in the database because when I close and open that screen, I can see the updated quantity. Nothing out of the ordinary happens in the code: onLoaderReset is not called, notifyChange gets called on the correct Uri in the contentprovider. Has anyone ever seen this issue?

When the quantity needs to get updated:

```
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CartTable.COLUMN_COUNT, quantity);
        String selection = CartTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + cartItemId;
        contentResolver.update(CartContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, cv, selection, null);
```

The CartContentProvider:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    int rowsUpdated;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case CART_ITEMS:
            rowsUpdated = this.database.update(CartTable.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    if(rowsUpdated > 0)
    {
        this.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
        this.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTS, null);
        this.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTS_PHOTOS, null);
        this.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_PHOTOS, null);
    }
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

When I create the CursorLoader:

```
return new CursorLoader(this.getView().getContext(), CartContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTS, projection, null, null, null);
```

So for example, I edit the quantity 20 times and 20 times onLoadFinished gets called with a new cursor. The 21st time and all times after that, the update happens but onLoadFinished is not called anymore.

When extra code is required, let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CursorLoader like this:

```
return new CursorLoader(this.getActivity(), CartContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCTS, projection, null, null, null);
```

use the fragment's Activity context, Also check where are you implementing the LoaderCallbacks interface, in the activity or in the fragment?

Comment: To rule out some context related issues: I just used the application context and the issue still happens. The loadercallbacks is implemented in the fragment, all logic happens in the fragment (create loader, receive cursor, show data, update database).